# One Facebook app for each domain and request_uri

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing a facebook-integration wrapper on top of Facebook PHP SDK. My app is kinda a backend for a product store. Many backends on different domains of course.

Since the initial request for access token require the `request_uri` param (that should match that in the app setting) should i create one facebook app for each backend?

```
request_uri = http://mydomain.com/admin/social/facebook_thanks.php
```

(this is the same as defined in application setting). If i add another domain (say: "anotherdomain.com") should `request_uri` be changed to this?

```
request_uri = http://anotherdomain.com/admin/social/facebook_thanks.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook will only redirect users to the domain set in your application settings, no matter what you change the request_uri to.

[image]

Comment: So i need to create one application for each backend i sell?

Comment: unless each backend is set to the same domain.